# Log4j Zip file fails sometimes

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using log4j rolling file appender with zip facility . Every hour it rolls the file and zip it . Sometimes it just fails to zip . so we have a unzip log file and also a zipped log file with same name but zero bytes . what could be the reason . this is configuration :

```
<RollingFile name="stat-log" fileName="${stat-log}"
            filePattern="${stat-log}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                    modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
```

i have added apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar in the class path and log4j version is 2.5

One more thing , the log files are huge , the zip which failed , has a log file with 30 GB size .

Comment: What have you considered and ruled out so far?

Comment: I am not sure , there are no error in logs about this . what i suspect is , it tries to zip the file , but the file size is huge and it took a lot of time and it fails sometimes because of this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/5edf43758f104affad9842753e66be173fc4d68a/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/RollingFileManager.java#L439
and
https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/5edf43758f104affad9842753e66be173fc4d68a/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/action/ZipCompressAction.java

The zip action is done as an asynchronous action, so logging can continue while the file is getting zipped. Any number of things can cause the behavior you are seeing as these asynchronous actions can be terminated, or if an exception happens then the zip and remove of the original file is not done. There is logging for most of these things so if you are not seeing log messages then it might be that it is still zipping that huge file, while logging continues.